# Unable to Generate a Facebook Preview/Thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, facebook-page

My website, www.thetroubadoursroad.com, a WordPress website, has always been able to generate a "preview" when I would copy/paste the article link into the status/link section of both my personal page and Facebook Page for the website.  It states there is a "circular redirect."  How do fix that issue and resume being able to generate a preview/thumbnail?

Thank you very much.

Nels Thoreson

Comment: It'd be helpful to know what plugin you're using to do this, and what the URL is that's breaking it. This is unanswerable as-is.

Comment: http://www.thetroubadoursroad.com/featured-artist-bruce-springsteen-dancing-in-the-dark/

Comment: It just generates this:  http://www.thetroubadoursroad.com/?p=771

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that page. You are being unclear.

Comment: When I put it in the Facebook debugger it says that I have a "circular redirect" error with the article URL, so it is not able to generate a preview.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ curl -I http://www.thetroubadoursroad.com/featured-artist-bruce-springsteen-dancing-in-the-dark/
```

Result:

```
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
```

Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908507/406-not-acceptable-for-a-post-in-my-wordpress-blog, this looks like a `mod_security` issue - it is seeing the HTTP request from Facebook as a potential hacking attempt and blocking it.

Comment: How do I fix the 406 not acceptable for a post in my wordpress blog issue?

Comment: Ask your host to fix their mod_security rules.